# Why Nginx with php7.4-fpm does not give an output?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fpm, php-7.4

I have installed nginx along with php7.4-fpm. The nginx and fpm are installed and running properly.
When i run the server no output shown in browser.Kindly tell me why the output of index.php file is not displayed at browser. when i try with localhost the window simply shows...

[image]

And when i use the server name as test.com

[image]

Configuration setting at

```
    /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com
```

is:-

[image]

Configuration settings at

```
 /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/test.conf
```

is:-

[image]

PHP file at the root directory :-

```
 /usr/share/nginx/test/index.php
```

[image]

Also:-

[image]

```
sudo less /var/log/php5-fpm.log
```

[image]

"nginx.conf" file in directory /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
 user www-data;
 worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Anything in the nginx logs?

Comment: no there no logs for nginx error.log

Comment: have you found where is the problem....

Comment: Please add a listing on /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

Answer (score 0):

According your nginx.conf parameters:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

All vhost config files are loading form `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` folders. But since your `test.com` file located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, it should not be loaded.

You have to put that file either at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` folder or make a link to it, like:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Then reload Nginx:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Comment: test.com is present in site-enabled.